# Django Tutorial Shenanigans

Tags: python, django

Aloha chaps,

Having a spot of bother with the Django tutorial

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

As you can see below, it is saying 'Question' isn't defined.

```
c:\Python34\Scripts\mysite>python manage.py makemigrations polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",        line
338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",  line
312, in execute
django.setup()
File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "c:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "c:\Python34\Scripts\mysite\polls\models.py", line 3, in <module>
class Question(models.Model):
File "c:\Python34\Scripts\mysite\polls\models.py", line 7, in Question
class Choice(models.Model):
File "c:\Python34\Scripts\mysite\polls\models.py", line 8, in Choice
question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
NameError: name 'Question' is not defined
```

Here is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If this is your exact file, i am surprised it is not yelling about an Indentation error !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't nest the classes. Get your indentation levels right. Choice needs to be at the same level as Question, not inside Question. Your wrong indentation here and the stack trace give it away.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
     question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Identation is the problem